# Tagging PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, metadata

Is it possible to "tag" a PostgreSQL database with meta-data?

Here is my intended use case: I have a database that goes through several workflow steps, and it would be nice to record somewhere *around* a database that a step has been taken. Of course there could be a table *inside* the database for recording this, but I am not supposed to change the schema for the task at hand.

Could/should e.g. custom options (e.g. `ALTER DATABASE db SET a.b = 'c'`) serve such a purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [a_horse commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224995/tagging-postgresql-database#comment442131_224995), a [COMMENT ON DATABASE db IS 'foo';](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) would be a simple option.

[`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) settings are for the duration of the transaction or session only. If you need to persist information beyond the current session, that won't do.

For more structured bookkeeping, maybe including a timestamp etc, consider a bookkeeping table in another database in the same db cluster - without altering the db in question at all. (Maybe in addition to a comment on the main db indicating the current status.) Sample psql session:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_meta;
\c db_meta
CREATE TABLE db_status_log (
  log_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, log_ts timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
, status text
);
```

Etc.

`\c db_meta` is the psql meta-command to connect to a db.